# Nativescript with angular collapse listview

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am following this solution [collapse listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665484/toggle-listview-content-in-nativescript-with-angular) to collapse a listview. when the user press hide I want to show the details of the items and when the user press show I want to and the details and show the name of the item. Currently from this solution, when the app is loaded, it doesn't show anything. But when the hide button is press the details are shown.

What I what to accomplish is to display the name when the app loads and when the user press on hide I want to hide the name and show the details.

```html
<GridLayout>

<ListView [items]="items">
<ng-template let-item="item">
    <GridLayout class="list-group-item" columns="*,auto">
       <Label col="0" textWrap="true" [text]="item.details" [visibility]="item.visible ? 'collapse' : 'visible'"></Label>
       <Label col=1 text ="show" [text]="item.visible ? 'hide' : 'show'" (tap)="toggle(item)"></Label>

    </GridLayout>
</ng-template>
</ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

```html
        export class Item{
        id: number;
        name: string;
        details: string;
        visible: boolean;
}
```

```html
  toggle(item: Item) {
            item.visible = !item.visible;
            //item.visible = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I adjust the view to fix it.

```html
GridLayout>
      <ListView [items]="details">
      <ng-template let-item="item">
          <GridLayout class="list-group-item" columns="*,auto">
             <Label col="0" textWrap="true" [text]="item.details" [visibility]="item.visible ? 'collapse' : 'visible'"></Label>
             <Label col="0" textWrap="true" [text]="item.title" [visibility]="item.visible ? 'visible' : 'collapse'"></Label>
             <Label col=1 text ="show" class="fas" [text]="item.visible ? '&#xf067;' : '&#xf068;'" (tap)="toggle(item)"></Label>

          </GridLayout>
      </ng-template>
      </ListView>
      </GridLayout>
```